# Flutter MAP how to know user reached destination or crossed stop

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation, location, google-maps-flutter

I am working with school tracking app. I have implemented [google_maps_flutter: ^2.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) package.
i have implemented direction, polygon.I am stuck with one point. **I want how to find out current bus is reached or crossed with my stop.**

please help me!!

I tried find out with difference with two latLang but we can't identify user is reached or crossed stops

```
double calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var a = 0.5 - cos((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 +
        cos(lat1 * p) * cos(lat2 * p) *
            (1 - cos((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;
    //it will return distance in KM
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }

// result will same if near to your stop or crossed stop
```

Comment: Hello! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to increase your chances of getting help from the community.